# Problem with keys in Hibernate one to one relationship tables

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have two simple class Automobil and Ford, they are add records to my Database relation OneToOne. When I check the result I see The keys are not added in turn. When I add a record to the Automobil table that stores a foreign key to the Ford table, I see that the ID number of the automobile record is 1 while the table Ford 2, and then automobile 3 and Ford 4 why this happens?

Automobil.class

```
@Entity(name = "Automobil")
@Table(name = "automobil")
public class Automobil {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;

private String auto;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn
private Ford ford;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getAuto() {
    return auto;
}

public void setAuto(String auto) {
    this.auto = auto;
}

public Ford getFord() {
    return ford;
}

public void setFord(Ford ford) {
    this.ford = ford;
}

}
```

Ford.Class

```
@Entity(name = "Ford")
@Table(name = "ford")
public class Ford {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;

private String model;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getModel() {
    return model;
}

public void setModel(String model) {
    this.model = model;
}

}
```

Main.class

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory =   Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("tutorialdb");
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    Automobil auto = new Automobil();
    Ford ford = new Ford();

    auto.setAuto("Ford");
    auto.setFord(ford);
    ford.setModel("Mustang");

    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(auto);

    entityManager.persist(ford);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

    entityManager.close();
    entityManagerFactory.close();

}

}
```

result: Automobil Table

```
id=1    auto=Ford   ford_id=2
id=3    auto=Ford   ford_id=4
```

result: Ford table

```
id=2 model=mustang
id=4 model=fiesta
```

for some reason the key won't create, why this is happening ?

```
 Error executing DDL "alter table automobil drop foreign key   FKovj5b90x7jrtqauuchxruywn3" via JDBC Statement
```

Answer (score 0):

This says that it's not droped not not created!

Error executing DDL "alter table automobil **drop** foreign key   FKovj5b90x7jrtqauuchxruywn3" via JDBC Statement

So everything seems to be fine.

You can remove @JoinColumn as you don't set any column name.

Comment: I can't find where is problem the ID number of primary and foreign key are not this same. In Automobil primary key is 1 but foreign key to Ford table is 2. When I add new record the number of promary key Automobil Table will be 3 and foregin key to Ford table 4. When I check result of table Ford I see record ID with number 2 and 4. I can't find why they don't add in turn as Automobil ID = 1 and Ford ID = 1, instead they add n + 1.

Comment: The are not the same because you don't have a GenerationStrategy set and Hibernate is using a table called hibernate_sequence and every id is comming from there

Comment: Ok thank you for show me the way, I have used @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) in both class and now is ok